# How can I edit strings/urls within a list?

Tags: python, list, url

I've scraped and created a list of URLs and am trying to replace a section of each url in the list.

Each URL contains the section '/season/1288' that I'm trying to remove. 'productions' is my list of urls, and this is the code I was using:

```
prod_lists = [str.replace('/season/1288', '') for i in productions]
print(prod_lists)
```

It returns the error

```
TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: shouldn't it be ```i.replace('/season/1288', '')```?

Comment: @ewong Hmm, that only seemed to remove some entire elements from the list. For context my list looks like this: ['https://www.ibdb.com/season/1288/broadway-production/springsteen-on-broadway-515480', 'https://www.ibdb.com/season/1288/broadway-production/the-waverly-gallery-518410'] but with about 30 or so URLs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a list using `list comprehension` in your code, you should use the variable i, not `str`.

```
productions = [
    '/season/1288/aaa',
    '/season/1288/bbb',
    '/season/1288/ccc',
]
prod_lists = [i.replace('/season/1288', '') for i in productions]
print(prod_lists)
```

This will print:

```
['/aaa', '/bbb', '/ccc']
```

The reason you received the error msg is because you called `replace` function using `str` class, not `str` instance. It automatically passes a `str` instance as a first parameter, known as `self` but, in this code `replace` cannot find a str instance to pass as a first parameter because `str` is a class, not an instance.

Interestingly, if you run a following code, explicitly passing `str` instance '/season/1288/ccc', you can see the result replaced by 1 without an error msg.

```
productions = ['/season/1288/aaa']
prod_lists = [str.replace('/season/1288/ccc', '/season/1288', '1') for i in productions]
print(prod_lists) # This prints: ['1/aaa']
```